# How to count how many times a function or a line of code is being called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am developing a web application in ruby on rails.Before pushing it to production i want to add a functionality in the code using which i can get how many times a particular function is being called.So that i can enhance the code which is being called frequently.And check the dead code which is not being called.

Comment: You should have a look at New Relic, a service that generates exactly the metrics (and much more) you are interested in (https://newrelic.com/application-monitoring). The Lite plan is free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to track how many times a Ruby method is called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732733/is-there-a-way-to-track-how-many-times-a-ruby-method-is-called)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can find some examples of AOP for Ruby-on-rails.
Like http://blog.arkency.com/2013/07/ruby-and-aop-decouple-your-code-even-more/

AOP will allow you to execute code before/adter/around a method for example without modifying the class itself.

It would be a good way to count method use without impacting your current code.

You can also take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396035/ruby-rails-prepend-append-code-to-all-methods)

Answer (score 0):

This functionality exists when running tests, but it actually measures how much code is covered by your tests. Check out [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov), you can use it together with rspec or cucumber, and definitely the last one should give you some sort of indication.

Instead of running tests, you could also run a simple script together with `simplecov`, to achieve kind of the same effect.

But if you are worried about code quality, I would urge you to look at [metric_fu](https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu): it will generate all kinds of statistics with regards to the quality of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *profiling*, and there are plenty of profilers for Ruby. Some of the best profiling tools on the planet exist on the Java platform, and they pretty much Just Work™ out-of-the-box with JRuby. For YARV, there is `ruby-prof`, for example.