# Is there a way to count how many times a Ruby method is called?

Tags: ruby, trace

Is there a way in Ruby to count how many times a method is called? I know that `caller.first` gives you the file name, line number, and caller method name, but couldn't find any further related information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `TracePoint` to run a block of code whenever a method is called, then filter based on the method name.

```
def foo() end

count = 0
name = :foo

TracePoint.trace(:call) do |t|
  count += 1 if t.method_id == name
end

count # => 0
foo
count # => 1
foo
count # => 2
```

`count` here is simply a local variable that is closed over by the `.trace` block. You can adjust this to be a constant, or an instance variable, or whatever best suits your use case.